# Reading and encoding html

Tags: php, html

I am trying to read and display the content of the title (contained in a h1 tag) from many HTML files. These files are all in the same folder.

This is what the html files look like :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN'>
<html> 
<head>   
    <title>A title</title> 
    <style type='text/css'>
    ... Styles here ...
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>&Ecirc;tre aidant</h1>
  <p>En g&eacute;n&eacute;ral, les aidants doivent &eacute;quilibrer...</p>
  ... more tags ...
</body>
```

I have tried to display the content from the H1 tag with this PHP script :

```
<?php 
foreach (glob("test/*.html") as $file) {
    $file_handle = fopen($file, "r");

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTMLfile($file);

    $title = $doc->getElementsByTagName('h1');
    if ( $title && 0<$title->length ) {
        $title = $title->item(0);
        $content = $doc->savehtml($title);
        echo $content;
    }
    fclose($file_handle);
}
?>
```

But the output contains wrong characters. For the example file, the output is :

```
ÃŠtre aidant
```

How can I achieve this output?

```
Être aidant
```

Comment: Are files saved as UTF8? Did you try to convert the string something like https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php#104325

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should state a charset in the `<head>` of your HTML document.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: Do you mean in the output document?

Comment: Yep, for all your `.html` files, you should have this declaration. Try it for one file and see if it works or not.

Comment: ok, I added `<head><meta charset="utf-8"></head>` before the output and the output is as I need, thx for the help!

Answer (score 0):

you need to use utf-8 encoding
change `echo $content to echo utf8_encode($content);`

Comment: thanks for the answer but the output becomes `ÃƒÂŠtre aidant`

Comment: if you remove utf8_encode than output will be Être aidant.
what is your expected output.